# Blender rendered videos not able to import to other editing software

Tags: rendering, export, import, video, external-applications

I have rendered an multiple kinds of animations with Blender and cant import the file in other programs how Sony Vegas, Adobe Premiere or DaVinci Resolve.
What ever i tried it was impossible. Tried render in in diffirent video and audio codecs, other extentions and turn on transperent mode off.
It isnt possible to import and edit far the animations in other editors in my computer.
What i did wrogg, have anybody similar experience ?

Answer (score 0):

Blender is not particularly good at ensuring that the video settings you select will produce a video in a format that is widely readable by other applications. Probably the most widely used format, although not the best is rendered in recent versions of Blender by selecting *FFmpeg Video* as the file format.  Under encoding select *MPEG-4* as the container. Under video select *MPEG-4 (divx)* and under audio *MP3*.  Do not change any of the other settings.

If this doesn't work you might have a bug.

There are other formats that Blender can output that should generate valid video but they will be playable by fewer players.

I am surprised you are having problems with Resolve.  It supports a v[ery wide range of formats.](https://documents.blackmagicdesign.com/SupportNotes/DaVinci_Resolve_15_Supported_Codec_List.pdf)

Comment: It concern videos with transperention, only. These are not recognised from other editors, if I deselect the transperency in renrering settings than it works. But I need the transperency. I tried all possible codecs now. Maybe it gives more participants whoes have the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

I always render as CODEC = MP4 and CONTAINER = MP4 but I also have to write the extension .mp4 after the file name eg. "MyMovie.mp4" so that other apps recognise the file type at a system level.